# I have an issue with a NullPointerException upon resuming my Android app and rendering the canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

my app currently crashes when you press the home or back button saying "Unfortunately, Rocks has crashed". I have narrowed it down to the line of code that reads:

```
// draws the canvas on the panel
this.gamePanel.render(canvas);
```

in this context:

```
package com.background.rocks;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MainThread extends Thread {

    private static final String TAG = MainThread.class.getSimpleName();

    // desired fps
    private final static int MAX_FPS = 50;
    // maximum number of frames to be skipped
    private final static int MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;
    // the frame period
    private final static int FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS;

    // Surface holder that can access the physical surface
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    // The actual view that handles inputs
    // and draws to the surface
    private Graphics gamePanel;

    // flag to hold game state 
    private boolean running;

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

    public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Graphics gamePanel) {
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
    }

@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");

    long beginTime; // the time when the cycle begun
    long timeDiff; // the time it took for the cycle to execute
    int sleepTime; // ms to sleep (<0 if we're behind)
    int framesSkipped; // number of frames being skipped 

    sleepTime = 0;

    while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing
        // in the surface
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                framesSkipped = 0; // resetting the frames skipped
                // update game state 
                this.gamePanel.update();
                // render state to the screen
                // draws the canvas on the panel
                this.gamePanel.render(canvas);
                // calculate how long did the cycle take
                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                // calculate sleep time
                sleepTime = (int) (FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                if (sleepTime > 0) {
                    // if sleepTime > 0 we're OK
                    try {
                        // send the thread to sleep for a short period
                        // very useful for battery saving
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }

                while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                    // we need to catch up
                    this.gamePanel.update(); // update without rendering
                    sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD; // add frame period to check if in next frame
                    framesSkipped++;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
            // an inconsistent state
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        } // end finally
    }
}
```

}

But I'm new to using canvas so I don't know how to fix it. It creates a NullPointerException so I'm assuming it's to do with when resuming the app or pausing the app the canvas isn't stored properly.

Edit: Graphics class (without imports):

```
package com.background.rocks;

public class Graphics extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private static final String TAG = Graphics.class.getSimpleName();

private MainThread thread;
private Player player;
private ArrayList<Rock> rocks = new ArrayList<Rock>();
private Random random = new Random();
private CountDownTimer countdown;

public Graphics(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    // create shape and load bitmap
    player = new Player(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player_orange), 540, 1500);

    // create the game loop thread
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

    // make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
    setFocusable(true);

    timer();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // at this point the surface is created and
    // we can safely start the game loop
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Surface is being destroyed");
    // tell the thread to shut down and wait for it to finish
    // this is a clean shutdown
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // try again shutting down the thread
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Thread was shut down cleanly");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // delegating event handling to the shape
        player.handleActionDown((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

        // check if in the lower part of the screen we exit
        if (event.getY() > getHeight() - 50) {
            thread.setRunning(false);
            ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Coords: x=" + event.getX() + ",y=" + event.getY());
        }
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        // the gestures
        if (player.isTouched()) {
            // the shape was picked up and is being dragged
            player.setX((int) event.getX());
            player.setY((int) event.getY());
        }
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // touch was released
        if (player.isTouched()) {
            player.setTouched(false);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

**public void render(Canvas canvas) {
    if (canvas != null) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        player.draw(canvas);
        Rock[] rockArray = rocks.toArray(new Rock[0]);
        for (Rock rock : rockArray) {
            rock.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}**

/**
 * This is the game update method. It iterates through all the objects and
 * calls their update method if they have one or calls specific engine's
 * update method.
 */
public void update() {
    Rock[] rockArray = rocks.toArray(new Rock[0]);
    for (Rock rock : rocks) {
        rock.update();
    }
}

public void timer() {
    if (countdown != null) {
        countdown.cancel();
    }
    countdown = new CountDownTimer(30000, 800) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            rocks.add(new Rock(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rock), random.nextInt(1080 - 1) + 1, 0));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            countdown.start();
        }
    }.start();
}

 }
```

**Edit 2:** So I managed to change my Render method in Graphics and so the app doesn't crash now when you press home or back, however when I try and resume the app I get a black screen. I'm assuming because it hasn't loaded the canvas back in, but I'm not sure how to do this, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Start running the thread once the surface gets created. i.e. when you get a callback `surfaceCreated()`, start the thread.

Code Snippet

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Where would I put this? I don't actually create a thread in this class it gets created in my Graphics class which I'll add the code for. Edit: Just realised I do this exact thing in my graphics class, do I need to do it in the MainThread class too? Cause I don't have a thread variable in it.

Comment: Would it be something to do with this (copied from my other reddit post on a different error) - I've noticed that after a while the app crashes since adding:
Rock[] rockArray = rocks.toArray(new Rock[0]);
to the render method. I get a ConcurrentModificationException at Java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573) at com.background.Graphics.render(Graphics.java:112) at com.background.rocks.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:62)
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late but what I did to fix it was I put a n if statement to test whether the canvas is still their before rendering and updating. Should look like this:

```
If (canvas != null){
    this.gamePanel.render (canvas);
    this.gamePanel.update ();
}
```

I think I followed the same tutorial as you, you will probobly encounter another issue after this on is solved. Im still looking for an answer to that issue. Hope this helps!